# MAMP Mysql seems to be installed correctly but not working as it should for localhost install on Mac OS X

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mamp

I've been trying for two days to get MAMP mysql server to start for a localhost install. Nothing in the volumes of reading and trying, I've done, has worked. I did manage to get some response from the mysql server offering a bit of hope that I'm closer, but I need some help to figure this out. So, thanks in advance for your help!

**The Environment:**
New install of Mac OS X 10.13.6 High Sierra on a mid 2011 iMac
New install of MAMP 5.7 (with mysql 5 +)
New install of Wordpress and
My website set up in the htdocs folder of MAMP
(an aside: I have the same environment set up on a 2008 Macbook Pro that MAMP, mysql and wordpress are working fine on, serving pages localhost flawlessly. So I basically made sure that all of the settings on the iMac setup are the same.)

**The Situation / Problem:**
When I start the MAMP application and the startup interface window displays, it appears that the Apache server starts, but mysql server does not, "cloud" and "open webstart page" do not become active and clickable. I can go to a browser and put "localhost:8888" in the address bar and get the following message (click the link to open image):
[Browser error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nLCx.png). This is a wordpress error with information that I don't understand, but it's encouraging because I can see there is some communication with MAMP, wordpress and mysql. I go to the file mentioned "Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1635" but I dont understand what it's telling me. Therefore I don't know what to do about it.

If I put "`http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/index.php`" in the browser to see if I can connect directly with mysql, I get the following error message (click the link to open image): [phpMyAdmin error message 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwJ0q.png)  Again, this is good because there is some communication, but I still don't know what the cause of the error is or how to fix it. I *HAVE* checked "the host, username and password in the configuration" and everything is a match. (Remember I have a cheatsheet of sorts in the other Macbook Pro setup to follow) Also, and this seems *REALLY* weird, if I put `http://localhost:8888/MAMP/` into the browser, I go to the MAMP start page, as if everything is normal!!! However if I click on the "My Website" link or anything in the "Tools" dropdown I will get one of the errors in the earlier photo links in this post.

Now, for the real puzzeler in my mind, when I decided to try the MAMP PRO interface to see if I could import a copy of my database, NOT A PROBLEM!!!!! with anything. Using that interface all I did was go to mysql, import the database and VOILA! Hot Cha Cha! Everything works like it's supposed to. No Errors.

So I quit MAMP PRO, restart the computer, and go into MAMP. Same problems as before. Oh and I didnt mention that in the last couple of days I have uninstalled, MAMP and re installed 3 times. All while reading and searching for a solution.

I'm really at a loss and would appreciate any insight to get the MAMP / mysql working as it should.

Thanks again for reading through this post.

EDIT: P.S. I've been using MAMP, installing it on other machines that I've had, since just after it come out. Never had too much problem setting up and using it... till now.

Comment: So when you start the servers in MAMP the mySQL switch is not going green? In that case, take a look at the error logs why it could not start. Did you check the port? Perhaps its not the same as in your Wordpress config? MAMP5 is upcoming with new mySQL8 as default. Are you sure Wordpress is capable of that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply :^) Yes, you understand. The green indicator for the mysql server does not come on during startup. Only Apache indicator comes on. Knowing that there are a couple of places that errors are generated to, (but not understanding which is relevant to the situation) I will start with the most visible in the directory hierarchy. That would be located at Applications/MAMP/logs/: there are 2- mysql_error.log and mysql_error.log.err I can post one or the other or both if you understand them.... Thanks

Comment: knowing the error message will always help :)

Comment: Thanks for your help and interest! Solved!!!! I kept at it nearly non stop. Then I figured how to use the terminal to run a start command from the file 'startMysql.sh'. Starts and stops normally now. Had to reinstall wordpress from a backup but now finally have everything running normal, I guess that's a benefit of being OCD'ed Thanks again ;^)